# Is the the cross product of two Bezier curves a Bezier curve?

Tags: geometry, cross-product, bezier-curve

For some geometric problem that I am trying to solve, I am interested 
in characterizing the cross product between a Bezier curve and its second order derivative.

So, let's $\mathbf{c}(t)$ be a Bezier curve, and $\ddot{\mathbf{c}}(t)$ it's derivative.

Is $\mathbf{w}(t) = \mathbf{c}(t)  \times \ddot{\mathbf{c}}(t)$ a Bezier curve?

If it is the case, is it also the case in general ?

Thanks a lot for your time and answers. Sincerely,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Henning Makholm One can say a little more.

Let us recall that a Bézier curve with degree $n$ (particular cases  $n=2$: quadratic, $n=3$ cubic) can be **defined** as any expression of the form:

$$\tag{1}\vec{OM}=\vec{u_0}+\vec{u_1}t+\vec{u_2}t^2+\vec{u_3}t^3+\cdots+\vec{u_{n-1}}t^{n-1}+\vec{u_n}t^n \ \ \text{with} \ \  \vec{u_n}\neq 0$$

(see example at the bottom of this text.)

(this well known result is due to the fact that every polynomial with degree $\leq n$ can be decomposed onto the Bernstein polynomials of order $n$ that constitute a basis of the vector space of polynomials with degree $\leq n$).

> **Result:** If $\mathbf{c}(t)$ describes a Bézier curve with degree $n$, the curve
>
> $$\mathbf{w}(t) = \mathbf{c}(t)  \times \ddot{\mathbf{c}}(t)$$
>
> still is a Bézier curve, with degree $\leq 2n-3.$

Proof: The second derivative of (1) is

$$\tag{2}\ddot{\vec{OM}}=2\vec{u_2}+6\vec{u_3}t+\cdots+(n-2)(n-1)\vec{u_{n-1}}t^{n-3}+n(n-1)\vec{u_n}t^{n-2}$$

Taking the cross product of (1) and (2), one gets, by distributivity:

$$\vec{u_0} \times 2\vec{u_2}+ \cdots + \vec{v}t^{n-3}+n(n-1)\underbrace{\vec{u_n}\times \vec{u_n}}_{\vec{0}}t^{2n-2}$$

with $\vec{v}:=2(n-1) \vec{u_{n-1}} \times \vec{u_{n-2}}$.

**Two particular cases:**

- (A) A quadratic Bézier curve is transformed into a straight line ($n=2 \to 2n-3=1$).
- (B) A cubic Bézier curve is transformed into a cubic Bézier curve  ($n=3 \to 2n-3=3$).

---

Example of a quadratic Bézier curve :

$$\vec{OM}=(1-t)^2\vec{OA}+2t(1-t)\vec{OB}+t^2\vec{OC}=\vec{OA}+2t\vec{AB}+t^2(\vec{BA}+\vec{BC}).$$

Answer (score 2):

*Every* parametric curve where each coordinate is a polynomial in the parameter can be expressed as a Bézier curve.

Thus also the cross product of Bézier curves. The *order* of the resulting curve will in general (except in degenerate cases) be the sum of the orders of the two curves you multiply -- so you can't, for example, multiply two cubic curves and expect to get a cubic curve back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering whether you could point out to any reference actually proving this ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers. I was in fact trying to compute the coefficients of this Bezier curve, while proving that the product is indeed a Bezier curve.

A friend helped me to obtain this:

We write:

- $\mathbf{c}(t) = \sum_{i=0}^n \mathbf{P}_i B^n_i(t)$
- $\mathbf{\ddot{c}}(t) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} \mathbf{Q}_i B^{n-2}_i(t)$

We can rewrite a Bernstein polynom as as [polynom of higher degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial#Properties) so:

- $\mathbf{\ddot{c}}(t) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \mathbf{R}_i B^{n}_i(t)$

Then

$\mathbf{w}(t) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n}( \mathbf{P}_i \times \mathbf{R}_j) B^{n}_i(t)B^{n}_j(t)$

$ B^{n}_i(t)B^{n}_j(t) ={{n}\choose{i}}{{n}\choose{j}} t^i(1-t)^{n-i}t^j(1-t)^{n-j}( \mathbf{P}_i \times \mathbf{R}_{k-i})$

We write $k = i + j$

$\mathbf{w}(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} [\sum_{i\in[0,n]\cap[k-n,k]}^{n} {{n}\choose{i}}{{n}\choose{k-i}} ( \mathbf{P}_i \times \mathbf{R}_{k-i})\mathbf{)} t^k(1-t)^{2n-k}]$

$\mathbf{w}(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{2n}{{2n}\choose{k}}t^k(1-t)^{2n-k}\alpha_k) $

with $\alpha_k = \sum_{i\in[0,n]\cap[k-n,k]}^{n} {{n}\choose{i}}{{n}\choose{k-i}} ( \mathbf{P}_i \times \mathbf{R}_{k-i})\mathbf{)} / {{{2n}\choose{k}}}$

Thus

$\mathbf{w}(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} B^{2n}_k(t)\alpha_k$

Does that seem right ?

Comment: It looks correct. But I am not certain that degree elevation, besides its theoretical interest, is good here, because it masks the fact the **real** degree of the resulting curve is  $\leq 2n-3$ and not $2n$.

Comment: (Ctd...) otherwise said, if I had the computation to do, I would work with the $\{ 1, t, t^2, t^3,...\}$ canonical basis and convert back into the Bernstein basis at the end.

Comment: Oh ok.Is there a way to convert back and forth to the canonical basis in arbitrary order ?

Comment: see the end of my remark.

Comment: This is great, I think I ll do just that. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, the correspondence between the canonical basis ans the Bernstein basis is through triangular matrices (see pages 8 and 9 of (http://www.idav.ucdavis.edu/education/CAGDNotes/Bernstein-Polynomials.pdf)).

Comment: I just found the document, thanks again for your help!